# What will be the value of *pointer + 2 in C++ in this case?

Tags: c++, pointers

Given a variable `long *ptr_long;`

And, the following:

[image: Memory Content]

What will be value of the operation *ptr_long + 2? Also, how?

I have tried the following: *ptr points to 0x00 right now that holds the contents '0x04'. Now, you take that and increase by 2 (4 bytes since it's a long type?). I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Read up on the precedence of operators and the answer will be ....

Comment: How long is `long`? Note: Dereferencing has higher precedence than the addition.

Comment: @learnerX  Strictly speaking there will be undefined behaviour.:)

Comment: @TomKarzes: you're looking in the wrong column.  The answer would be (0x04) + 2 == 0x06.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

```
*pointer + 2
```

is parsed as

```
(*pointer) + 2
```

rather than

```
*(pointer + 2),
```

so it means "dereference the pointer, then add two to the number you get as a result" rather than "go forward two objects, then dereference the pointer you get." In this case, you should get 6 (0x04 + 2).

If you add parentheses to get `*(pointer + 2)`, you'd get back 0x0c assuming that each `long` is four bytes (which I suspect given that you're only given sixteen bytes of memory), since `pointer + 2` means "skip forward by 2 * `sizeof(long)` bytes."

Comment: I don't think that we are derefrencing the pointer. The question before this one asked for value of: *(ptr_long+2) and this is a different case. The answer for this one should be 0x0F. But I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: @learnerX templatetypedefs answer is absolutely correct. So either you have mistyped the question, misunderstood the question or you have the wrong answer. An expression to actually get 0xF would be `*(pointer + 1) + 2`

Comment: @learnerX: if you've got an expression with `*` in front of a pointer, you're dereferencing it.  And I don't see any simple expression that would give `0x0F`.  Why do you think that's the answer? (And why didn't you mention that in the question?) It's possible that whoever told you that the answer was `0x0F` was simply wrong.

Comment: @learnerX If your homework is a cumulative set of problems (viz. the operations done in one problem carry over to the next one), you might get a different answer. But as it stands and is presented to us now, templatetypedef's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your system,
in most cases the answer is:

```
*ptr + 2 = 0x6 
*(ptr + 2) = 0xc
```

A long type is coded on 4 bytes for 32 bits systems, and on 8 bytes for 64 bits systems,

Depending on your system and CPU, your memory status may be as following :

```
0x00 : 04 00 00 00
0x04 : 0d 00 00 00
0x08 : 0c 00 00 00
0x0c : 0a 00 00 00

or

0x00 : 00 00 00 04
0x04 : 00 00 00 0d
0x08 : 00 00 00 0c
0x0c : 00 00 00 0d
```

or ( for 64 bits systems ):

```
0x00 : 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x08 : 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x10 : 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x18 : 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Your example is closer to a 32 bits system case, 
in this case :

```
# if ptr is a long pointer :
*ptr + 2 = 0x6      // the ( content of the long value at the adress 0x00 ) + 2 = 0x04 + 0x02
*(ptr + 2) = 0xc    // the content of adress 0x10    ( 0x00 + 2 as long size ) = 0x00 + 0x10 ( 16 in decimal)
```

it is good to know that :
*(ptr + 2) = *ptr[2]

```
ptr   -->0x00 : 04 00 00 00 
         0x04 : 0d 00 00 00 
ptr+2 -->0x08 : 0c 00 00 00  
         0x0C : 0a 00 00 00
```

## contrariwise:

## if ptr is a char pointer :

```
*ptr + 2 = 0x6      // the ( content of the char/byte value at the adress 0x00 ) + 2
*(ptr + 2) = 0x0    // the content of adress 0x02   ( 0x00 + 2 as char size ) = 0x00 + 0x02 ( 2 in decimal)

                ptr    ptr+2=0x02
                  |     |
         0x00 : (04)00(00)00 
         0x04 :  0d 00 00 00 
         0x08 :  0c 00 00 00  
         0x0C :  0a 00 00 00
```

In this case :
if for example a new pointer of type long  (long *)ptr2 is initialized by the ptr+2 value,
In 32 bits, the content at the adresse pointed by ptr2 will be : 00 00 0d 00

```
         0x00 : 04 00 (00 00 
         0x04 : 0d 00) 00 00 
         0x08 : 0c 00 00 00 
         0x0C : 0a 00 00 00
```

In 64 bits, the content of the adresse pointed by ptr2 will be : 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 00

```
0x00 : 04 00 (00 00 00 00 00 00
0x08 : 0d 00 ) 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x10 : 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x18 : 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

in both cases the value is the same :
*ptr2 + 2 = 0x0d02   // the ( content of the long value at the adress 0x02 ) + 2

but in 32 bits system :
*(ptr2 + 2) = 0x0a00    // the content of adress 0x0a    ( 0x02 + 2 as long ( 4 bytes) size ) = 0x02 + 0x08 
                        // the value is 0x0a00 = ( 00 00 00 0a )

```
               adress 0x0a
                       |
         0x08 : 0c 00(00 00
         0x0C : 0a 00)00 00
```

but in 64 bits system :
*(ptr2 + 2) = 0x12    // the content of adress 0x12    ( 0x02 + 2 as long (8 bytes) size ) = 0x02 + 0x10 
                      // the value is 0x0a00

```
               adress 0x12
                       |
         0x10 : 0c 00(00 00 00 00 00 00 
         0x18 : 0a 00)00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I prurpose you to compile and run the follow C programme :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void long_hexa_print( long *p )
{
 char *ptr = (char *)p;
 int size=sizeof(*p);
 printf ("0x%x : ", p  );
 for ( int i=0; i<size; i++){printf ( "0x%x " ,  *(ptr + i) );}
 printf ("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
   // char * string = "REVERSE";
    //reverse(string);

    int j=4;
    long *long_ptr =  (long *)malloc((j*sizeof(long))+1);
    char *ptr = (char *)long_ptr;

    char *  char_ptr2;
    int *   int_ptr2;
    long *  long_ptr2;


     long_ptr[0]=0x4;  // 4
     long_ptr[1]=0xb;  // 11
     long_ptr[2]=0xc;  // 12
     long_ptr[3]=0xa;  // 10

    char_ptr2 = (char *)( ptr + 2 );  // or (char *) ptr[2] 
    int_ptr2  = (int *)( ptr + 2 );
    long_ptr2 = (long *)( ptr + 2 );

    printf ("\n=== Sizes of types ====\n\n");
    printf ("Size of char = %d\n", sizeof(char));
    printf ("Size of long = %d\n\n", sizeof(long));

    printf ("\n=== Memory status ====\n\n");
    long_hexa_print( long_ptr );
    long_hexa_print( long_ptr + 1);
    long_hexa_print( long_ptr + 2);
    long_hexa_print( long_ptr + 3);
    long_hexa_print( long_ptr + 4);

    printf ("\n=== Values of pointers ====\n\n");
    printf ("long_ptr     = 0x%x\n",  long_ptr );
    printf ("long_ptr + 1 = 0x%x\n",  long_ptr + 1 );
    printf ("long_ptr + 2 = 0x%x\n\n",  long_ptr + 2 );

    printf ("* long_ptr + 2  = 0x%x\n",  * long_ptr + 2 );
    printf ("*(long_ptr + 2) = 0x%x\n",  *(long_ptr + 2) );
    printf ("  long_ptr[2]   = 0x%x\n\n",  long_ptr[2] );


    printf ("&long_ptr[0] = 0x%x\n", & long_ptr[0] );
    printf ("&long_ptr[1] = 0x%x\n", & long_ptr[1] );
    printf ("&long_ptr[2] = 0x%x\n\n", & long_ptr[2] );

    printf ("\n##### char *ptr = (char *)long_ptr; ##### \n");
    for ( int i=0; i<=7; i++){printf ( "ptr+%d     = 0x%x\n",  i, *(ptr + i) );}


    printf ("\n=== Values of contents ====\n\n");
    printf ("*long_ptr    = 0x%x\n", *long_ptr );
    printf ("*(long_ptr) = 0x%x\n\n", *(long_ptr) );
    printf ("long_ptr[0]  = 0x%x\n",  long_ptr[0] );
    printf ("long_ptr[1]  = 0x%x\n",  long_ptr[1] );
    printf ("long_ptr[2]  = 0x%x\n\n",  long_ptr[2] );
    printf ("*(long_ptr+0) = 0x%x\n", *(long_ptr+0) );
    printf ("*(long_ptr+1) = 0x%x\n", *(long_ptr+1) );
    printf ("*(long_ptr+2) = 0x%x\n\n", *(long_ptr+2) );

    printf ("char_ptr2 = 0x%x\n", *char_ptr2 );
    printf ("int_ptr2  = 0x%x\n", *int_ptr2 );
    printf ("long_ptr2 = 0x%x\n\n", *long_ptr2 );

    printf ("*( ptr)   = 0x%x\n", *( ptr));
    printf ("*( ptr+1) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 1));
    printf ("*( ptr+2) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 2));
    printf ("*( ptr+3) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 3));
    printf ("*( ptr+4) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 4));
    printf ("*( ptr+5) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 5));
    printf ("*( ptr+6) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 6));
    printf ("*( ptr+7) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 7));
    printf ("*( ptr+8) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 8));
    printf ("*( ptr+9) = 0x%x\n\n", *( ptr + 9));

    printf ("(long *)( ptr + 4) = 0x%x\n", *( ptr + 4));
    printf ("(long *)( ptr + 4) = %d\n\n", *( ptr + 4));

    printf ("(long *)( ptr + 8) = 0x%x\n", (long *)( ptr + 8));
    printf ("(long *)( ptr + 8) = %d\n\n", (long *)( ptr + 8));

    return 0;
}
```

The result will look like the following :

```
=== Sizes of types ====

Size of char = 1
Size of long = 8


=== Memory status ====

0x10350 : 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0x10358 : 0xb 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0x10360 : 0xc 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0x10368 : 0xa 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0x10370 : 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0

=== Values of pointers ====

long_ptr     = 0x10350
long_ptr + 1 = 0x10358
long_ptr + 2 = 0x10360

* long_ptr + 2  = 0x6
*(long_ptr + 2) = 0xc
  long_ptr[2]   = 0xc

&long_ptr[0] = 0x10350
&long_ptr[1] = 0x10358
&long_ptr[2] = 0x10360


##### char *ptr = (char *)long_ptr; #####
ptr+0     = 0x4
ptr+1     = 0x0
ptr+2     = 0x0
ptr+3     = 0x0
ptr+4     = 0x0
ptr+5     = 0x0
ptr+6     = 0x0
ptr+7     = 0x0

=== Values of contents ====

*long_ptr    = 0x4
*(long_ptr) = 0x4

long_ptr[0]  = 0x4
long_ptr[1]  = 0xb
long_ptr[2]  = 0xc

*(long_ptr+0) = 0x4
*(long_ptr+1) = 0xb
*(long_ptr+2) = 0xc

char_ptr2 = 0x0
int_ptr2  = 0x0
long_ptr2 = 0x0

*( ptr)   = 0x4
*( ptr+1) = 0x0
*( ptr+2) = 0x0
*( ptr+3) = 0x0
*( ptr+4) = 0x0
*( ptr+5) = 0x0
*( ptr+6) = 0x0
*( ptr+7) = 0x0
*( ptr+8) = 0xb
*( ptr+9) = 0x0

(long *)( ptr + 4) = 0x0
(long *)( ptr + 4) = 0

(long *)( ptr + 8) = 0x10358
(long *)( ptr + 8) = 66392
```

I hope this will help you to better understand pointers

Comment: both sizeof(long int) and sizeof(uintptr_t) report 8 bytes (not 4 bytes) on my ubuntu 15.10 (64) machine.

Comment: `*(ptr + 2)` is the content of 0x0***8*** as a long (assuming 4-byte longs)